# I have a bug in my nextjs/tailwind project, the font I am putting in, works on the pc but not on the cell phone

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm importing the googleFonts font into my Globals.css file and it's still not working on mobile
my globals.css :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  }

html,
body {
max-width: 100vw;
overflow-x: hidden;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

I am also declaring the source in the tailwind file
my tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'raleway': ['Raleway', 'sans-serif'],
    },
    extend: {
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I want the font I am trying to put to be the default in the project

Comment: Does this help https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts ?

Comment: It doesn't work either, and the strange thing is that on the computer browser the font is correct, but on the cell phone it is the default tailwind font

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproduction on codesandbox?